# Integrate Socket.io to an Angular.js boilerplate

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, coffeescript, socket.io

So, I'm super lost.

I have a vanilla project that I built from [here](http://product.moveline.com/angularjs-coffeescript-bootstrap-karma-tests-boilerplate-in-10-minutes-or-less.html)

Essentially it builds a basic project that comes pre-packaged with Grunt, CoffeeScript, Angular and Bootstrap. The only thing I'm missing is to add Socket.io. Now, here's where I'm painfully lost. For what I understand, I should use npm to install socket, import it in my list of scripts and then do some initial setup that more or less looks like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

server.listen(port, function () {
  console.log('Server listening at port %d', port);
});
```

And then refer to the `io` variable for all the sockety goodness.

Now, this doesn't work for me at the moment for various reasons. First off, I don't have an app.js file where to add all of that initial socket.io setup. My project looks more like:

```
├── app
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── scripts
│   │   ├── app.coffee
│   │   └── controllers
│   │       ├── about.coffee
│   │       └── main.coffee
│   ├── styles
│   │   └── main.scss
│   └── views
│       ├── about.html
│       └── main.html
├── bower.json
├── Gruntfile.js
├── package.json
├── README.md
├── server.js
```

Where app.cofee is the ng-app file with the application setup.

Now, I could add the setup at the top of my Gruntfile, unsure whether this is what I'm supposed to do but this does serve the `socket.js.io` file that I'm supposed to import in my index.html. However, I have some issues with that.

So, first issue, putting the setup in my gruntfile does not make the `io` variable available in my app.coffee. Which I believe that that is what I want in order to call the various Socket methods like `io.connect();`

Secondly, this part makes me feel weird

```
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
server.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('Server listening at port %d', port);
});
```

This is serving the `/socket.io/socket.io.js` file on the port 3000 while my app runs on the port 9000. I can't however just point to the port 9000 without running into port-being-used issues. The reason I see this as an issue is that is forcing me to link it with something like `<script src="http:localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>` which wouldn't work if I'm serving the page to another host. It would be much more easier if all the javascript is served on the same place. I could make a link to node_modules/socket.io/lib/socket.io.js but that seems like a patchy answer. Is there a more.... proper way of doing it?

And lastly, there's 1 thing I haven't find good information about. Ideally, I would want a server.coffee file where I can store sensitive information that can only be accessed trough socket calls. I don't know how to do that. Like is grunt who's supposed to know about that file and then somehow my io.emit calls will be able to reach it?